# calling legacy function with shared pointer

Tags: c++

i am trying to call a legacy function, which takes normal pointer parameter, with a shared pointer and i am getting the following error:

I have tried to convey the idea, by a simple example, what i am doing. I cannot change the parameter to display(), as it is in legacy and is being used by many other modules..But from my function, i am using shared pointer to call display. Is it correct ? Can you please suggest/advice ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

void display(int * x)
{
    cout << endl << "Pointer value is = %x" << *x;
}
int main(){

    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr( new( int ) );

    *ptr =5;

    display(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

**sh.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sh.cpp:17: error: cannot convert 'boost::shared_ptr' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void display(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the function attempt to free the pointer? If not, the best thing to do is to use shared_ptr's get() method, like so:

```
display(ptr.get());
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answers..was really helpful..i have one more question in the same term..if we are using a legacy code to get a pointer which returns <char *>, can i use the boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char> pData = legacy_function(a, b, c);: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot
convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' Sorry for basic questions, i am basically c programmer

Comment: You should do the following: `boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char>(function_that_returns_pointer());`. But there is a subtle problem with using shared_ptr with legacy pointers: the memory might have been allocated with malloc() and should be deallocated with free(), while boost shared_ptr and shared_array probably use delete and delete[] operators respectively. And you should never try to `delete` memory that was `malloc()ated`

Comment: thanks a lot ! it works...one doubt : dont we need c++ type of typecasting here ? i mean like reinterpret_cast etc ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw pointer from `boost::shared_ptr` use the `get()` method.